# Click a class in iframe to execute parent jquery

Tags: jquery, dialog

Thanks reading this....

I have a class="test1" on main page, and main page have iframe created dynamically,which then have element with class="test1". The aim is whenever "test1" clicked a code is executed...say alert("hey");

Below code add iframe.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click",".add_movie_button", function (event) {          
    event.preventDefault();

    iframe = $('<iframe id="iframe_add_movie" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
    var search_string = $("#search").val(); 

   $('#add_movie_dialog').append(iframe).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        dialogClass: "no-title",
        resizable:false,
        modal:true,
        position: 'center',
        height: 600,    
        width:400,          
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('#iframe_add_movie').attr('src','addmovie.php?search_string='+search_string);
            $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden'); //this line does the actual hiding
       }    
   });


   //click outside to close 
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").on("click", function() {
        $("#add_movie_dialog").dialog( "close" );       
    });
});
```

Need help as how click on class="test1" in iframe with open alert("hay") in parent

Comment: Alerts are blocking events.  You can't do anything while an alert is active, frame or no frame.

Or, I mis-interpreted your question as the language is very difficult to understand.

Comment: Alerts are blocking events----pls explain. I am using alert to check if code is working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use something like:

```
iframe = $('<iframe id="iframe_add_movie" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>').load(function(){
    $(this).contents().find('p').click(function(){
        alert('bar');
    });
});
```

This will need to come after you create the iFrame (iframe_add_movie), **and after the page has been loaded** (hence the .load() handler).

Note that if the iframe source is pointing at another domain, you won't be able to access the contents because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: sorry friend its not working, I tried this but still not working. `$('#iframe_add_movie').contents().find('.test1').on( "click", function () {
         alert("hello");
     });`

Comment: @user3525233 I've updated my answer.  I can't do a fiddle because of the Same Origin Policy, but this works when I've tested locally! You must bind _after_ the page is loaded in the iframe.

Comment: thanks dave, your answer gave me clues to work. But can you help changing the height of dialog with height of iframe.

Comment: You're welcome. You're specifying height in the code above.  `height: 600,` in the dialog call, and `height="100%` on the iframe element. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: height: 600,----is for dialog box and height="100% is for iframe to full space. I am thinking next to get height() of iframe and then declare in dialog height...but not able to achieve it....any guess

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. height:100% on the iframe will cause it to fill the height of the parent element (the dialog). You could just use ['auto'](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-height) as the height on the dialog?

Comment: "not working" isn't helpful, and this is now going off-topic. **Please avoid extended discussions in comments.** - I'd suggest posting a new question to try and resolve the problem you're now having, as it's different from the original question.

Comment: thanks for your efforts...will try to post new question soon.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting as this worked for me...and hope future readers may benefit.

below is dialog box

`<div class="pure-g" id="add_movie_dialog" title="Add Movie">
    <iframe id="iframe_add_movie" name="iframe_add_movie" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>`

this is jquery used

`   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click",".add_movie_button", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

```
    var search_string = $("#search").val();


    $('#add_movie_dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: "no-title",
        resizable:false,
        height:600, 
        width: 400,
        modal:true,
        position: 'center',         

        open: function (event, ui) {
                $('#iframe_add_movie').attr('src','addmovie.php?search_string='+search_string);
                $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden'); 

                $('#iframe_add_movie').load(function() {

                    var $content = $("#iframe_add_movie").contents();
                    $content.find("body").on( "click", ".search_movie", function() {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var clickedID = this.id.split("-"); 
                        var m_id = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array

                        //  Use transfer effect         
                        $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $("#load_area") }, 1000);

                        load_movie(m_id); ///some function to do stuff  

                    });     

                });                     
            },          



    });

    $('#add_movie_dialog').dialog("open");


    //click outside to close 
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").on("click", function() {
        $("#add_movie_dialog").dialog( "close" );                   
    });

});
```

});`